# Overriding TalkBack announcements

Tags: java, android, android-layout, accessibility, talkback

I am using a linear layout with multiple TextViews and LinearLayout within. Example Screen:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <Movie LinearLayout>
     <TextView>
     <LinearLayout>
     <TextView>
  </MovieLinearLayout>
  <LinearLayoutCast>
  <LinearLayoutDirector>
  <..>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Whenever I access that screen, TalkBack speaks "Showing item x of y" which is really annoying because it's rather movie information and not a list as such. How can I override TalkBack from speaking "item x of y"? Is it possible using `sendAccessibilityEvent`?

Answer (score 0):

Add an  android:contentDescription property to them.  See http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/accessible-app.html for more advice

Comment: It won't override the announcement I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at the `View.AccessibilityDelegate` methods.  Find the proper view and override the delegate methods for that view.  You most likely want to override `onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup host, View child, AccessibilityEvent event)` though you could look into the other delegate methods as well.

Comment: I could override most of the announcements using these methods except "Showing Item x of y".. Do you know if there exists a way to override that as well? If yes, can you please show it with an example for better understanding.

Comment: Every view has a View.AccessibilityDelegate that controls these announcements, you just have to find the right one.  If you were able to accomplish this with some of your views, any example I came up with would look a lot like what you have already figured out.